# Is there a way to read a network log file directly from the Android device using a Linux tail command like?

Tags: logging

Is there a way to do what's asked in the topic subject for unrooted and/or rooted phones?

I'd like to read from a system log file instead of constantly listening the network activity for battery saving purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any SSH client to establish a connection to your host and tail the desired file.

*This will not help you saving the battery, since the tail command or any other that collects "off-site" information, needs an active connection that uses network, that in turn consumes more battery.*

---

Personally I use [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) by Kenny Root and Jeffrey Sharkey available from Google Play Store for free.

> ConnectBot is a powerful open-source Secure Shell (SSH) client. It can manage simultaneous SSH sessions, create secure tunnels, and copy/paste between other applications.
>
> This client allows you to connect to Secure Shell servers that typically run on UNIX-based servers.